# How to undo an operation in qiskit on jupyter notebook?

Tags: qiskit, programming, hadamard

I am not able to undo an operation. For example, I want a single Hadamard gate on a single qubit but by mistake two Hadamard gate added. Now I want to remove one of them without interrupting kernel. Is there any easy way. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Inside a jupyter notebook, you could easily remove a gate from your code by removing a line such as circuit.h(0).

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I wanted to say. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the last gate you can do `qc.data.pop()`.

Example:

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(1)
qc.h(0)
qc.draw('text')
```

output:

```
     ┌───┐
q_0: ┤ H ├
     └───┘
```

Then:

```
qc.data.pop()
qc.draw('text')
```

output:

```
q_0:
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Frank. It helps a lot for beginners like me.